# Reference PHP array by multiple indexes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This may be some sort of weird longer shortcut, and please correct me if I'm mistaken in this train of thought...

I have a matrix of data that looks like:

```
unique_id | url | other random data...
unique_id | url | other random data...
unique_id | url | other random data...
```

I want to be able to reference an item by either it's url, or it's unique_id - is there a fancy way to do this?

I suppose the cheating solution would be to just make two arrays, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Not really, no.  Just make two arrays.  The overhead is minimal (well, depending on how big your arrays are).

Comment: Do you need to modify the "random data" once it's in the array?  And it it possible for a unique_id and a URL to collide?

Comment: Don't *duplicate* "other random data" ("DRY" concept). The cleanest solution is to have one array that maps `unique_id` to `other random data`, then a second array that maps `url` to `unique_id`. That is the purpose of `unique_id`s: to provide a concise and efficient "handle" that represents a given record (row) of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function selectByIdOrURL($array, $data) {
    foreach($array as $row) {
       if($row['unique_id'] == $data || $row['url'] == $data) return $row;
    }
    return NULL;
}

$array = array(
           array('unique_id' => 5, 'url' => 'http://blah.com'),
           array('unique_id' => 3, 'url' => 'http://somewhere_else.com')
         );
$found = selectByIdOrURL($array, 5); //array('unique_id' => 5, 'url' => 'http://blah.com')
$nfound = selectByIdOrURL($array, 10); //NULL
```

Comment: Is the only way to iterate the data? I suppose it's not a huge deal, but I'm really curious if you can have multiple indexes for arrays (generally speaking)

Comment: @Bob, no, there is no way to have multiple indexes for arrays.

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  The fastest approach (for access times) is to have two arrays, one with the unique_id as the key, the other with the URL, and both with all the data as the value.  Jacob's answer will use slightly less memory, but will need to iterate the whole array each time you reference something; my approach will use slightly more memory, but will retrieve the results faster.

Comment: That's a shame... I guess just iterating it isn't so bad

Comment: Any fancy solution would involve iteration behind the scenes anyway.

Answer (score 14):

Only way I can think of that doesn't involve iterating the array for each search (see Jacob's answer) is to store references to each item in two arrays.

**Edit**: As the URLs and IDs cannot collide, they may be stored in the same reference array (thanks Matthew)

```
$items; // array of item objects
        // Use objects so they're implicitly passed by ref

$itemRef = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $itemRef[$item->unique_id] = $item;
    $itemRef[$item->url] = $item;
}

// find by id
$byId = $itemRef[$id];

// find by url
$byUrl = $itemRef[$url];
```

You could probably encapsulate this nicely using a collection class that implements `getById()` and `getByUrl()`. Internally, it could store the references in as many arrays as is necessary.

Of course, what you're essentially doing here is creating indexed result sets, something best left to database management systems.

Comment: Also, you can put them in the same array (e.g. `$items`) if you choose.  It might be slightly confusing, but Bob said the keys can't collide.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. They don't collide, but it seems a little scary from a vulnerability stand point (for example a lookup that was forced using a url instead of a unique_id). Nice technique though

Comment: @Bob It's similar to when you retrieve database records using a `fetch_both` method where the result contains both numeric and string indexes. Speaking of indexes, if this data does come from a DB, you're probably better off applying indexes to the ID and url fields and doing single fetches to retrieve nominated records.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - you *could* put them in the same array, but its cleaner to have a second array that maps `url` to `unique_id`.  Keep separate concepts separate.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your fancy solution was only available as of **PHP 5.5**.
You can combine the use of [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to fetch your entry in a single line of code:

```
$items = [
    [
     'unique_id' => 42,
     'url' => 'http://foo.com'
    ],
    [
     'unique_id' => 57,
     'url' => 'http://bar.com'
    ],
    [
     'unique_id' => 36,
     'url' => 'http://example.com'
    ],

];

$bar = $entries[array_search(57, array_column($items, 'unique_id'))];

var_dump($bar);

//outputs
array (size=2)
    'unique_id' => int 57
    'url' => string 'http://bar.com' (length=14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely an object would be the easy way?

```
class Item {
    public $unique_url;
    public $url;
    public $other_data;

    public function __construct($unique_url, $url, $other_data)
    {
        $this->unique_url = $unique_url;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->other_data = $other_data;
    }
}



class ItemArray {
    private $items = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function push(Item $item)
    {
        array_push($items, $item); //These may need to be reversed
    }

    public function getByURL($url)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->url = $url)
            {
                return $item;
            }
        }
    }

    public function getByUniqueURL($url)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            if($item->unique_url = $unique_url)
            {
                return $item;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it with

```
$itemArray = new ItemArray();
$item = new Item("someURL", "someUniqueURL","some other crap");
$itemArray->push($item);

$retrievedItem = $itemArray->getItemByURL("someURL");
```

This technique has a little extra overhead due to object creation, but unless you're doing insane numbers of rows it would be fine.