# How to find entry by object property from an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

The array looks like:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 420
            [name] => Mary
         )

[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 10957
            [name] => Blah
         )
...
```

And I have an integer variable called `$v`.

How could I select an array entry that has an object where the `ID` property has the `$v` value?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You either iterate the array, searching for the particular record (ok in a one time only search) or build a hashmap using another associative array.

For the former, something like this

```
$item = null;
foreach($array as $struct) {
    if ($v == $struct->ID) {
        $item = $struct;
        break;
    }
}
```

See this question and subsequent answers for more information on the latter - [Reference PHP array by multiple indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405281/reference-php-array-by-multiple-indexes)

Comment: setting $item to null is not needed.

Comment: Oops, there it is :) That is in case the sought item is not in the array. Alternatively, you could use `isset($item)` but I prefer initialising variables properly

Comment: For those of you with key values set to strings use `if($v == $struct["ID"]){...`

Answer (score 106):

```
$arr = [
  [
    'ID' => 1
  ]
];

echo array_search(1, array_column($arr, 'ID')); // prints 0 (!== false)
```

Above code echoes the *index* of the matching element, or `false` if none.

To get the corresponding element, do something like:

```
$i = array_search(1, array_column($arr, 'ID'));
$element = ($i !== false ? $arr[$i] : null);
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) works both on an array of arrays, and on an array of objects.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the preferred answer. Is it because you are calling two functions?

Comment: I think I was too late for the party ;) Its shortage and readability without any loops and breaks would make it reasonable. But have not benchmarked it yet. You have a lot of of options in PHP to achieve the same.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Also works with an array of objects in PHP 7.  
For PHP 5: array_search($object->id, array_map(function($object) { return $object->id; }, $objects));  
For PHP 7: array_search($object->id, array_column($objects, 'id'));

Comment: This is not the preferred answere because op asks for array of objects and this answere only handle pure arrays.

Comment: thats not correct. this code handles array of objects / non flat arrays

Comment: Here is a reference to the answer at php documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635

Comment: At first this answer looked wrong to me, but then I realized that it returns the *index*. To get the *element  at that index*, do something like: `$i = array_search(...); $element = ($i !== false ? $arr[$i] : null);`  Adding that to the answer.

Comment: This requires the properties in the object to be public. This is the case in the mentioned problem, but for other users with named classes and private properties, this solution wont work.

Comment: This is the most preferred solution in PHP context. but the solution above is applicable across all programming language.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Simple, concise and most importantly; gets the job done

Answer (score 77):

[YurkamTim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694792/662581) is right. It needs only a modification:

After function($) you need a pointer to the external variable by "use(&$searchedValue)" and then you can access the external variable. Also you can modify it.

```
$neededObject = array_filter(
    $arrayOfObjects,
    function ($e) use (&$searchedValue) {
        return $e->id == $searchedValue;
    }
);
```

Comment: You're right about the modification and it is kind of a neat method, but I tested the speed compared to iterating through the object - yourself, because like @phil pointed out, array_filter is doing this too - and this method is taking about five times longer. My test object isn't a big one, so that might get even worse.

Comment: The `&` is not required when importing `$searchedValue` into the closure scope. The `&` is used to create a reference which is only needed if `$searchedValue` has been modified inside the closure.

Comment: That's cool. I didn't know PHP could do things like that. I thought using `global` was the only was to share data in functions! But it's a pity if this is indeed slow. :(

Comment: TS asked for a single entry, this code returns an array.

Comment: [YurkaTim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694792/199364) has been updated to include `use ($searchedValue)`. As StefanGehrig says in his comment, you don't need `&` i.e. `use (&$searchedValue)` unless you need to *modify* $searchedValue.

Answer (score 41):

I've found more elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166198/find-array-key-in-objects-array-given-an-attribute-value). Adapted to the question it may look like:

```
$neededObject = array_filter(
    $arrayOfObjects,
    function ($e) use ($searchedValue) {
        return $e->id == $searchedValue;
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 but `array_filter` returns an array, and won't stop at the first value found.

Comment: well, it depends ;) if I have array of few items I'd prefer array_filter over hand made loop, considering it's built in php function.

Comment: It is not recognizing `$searchedValue` inside the function. But outside it is.

Comment: For starters, this code doesn't work as `$searchedValue` is outside of the closure scope. Secondly, how do you think these array methods work? They all loop over the array internally

Comment: In the time of multi cores, this - in other programming environments unfortunately - could be processed in parallel, the loop above not necessarily

Comment: To use `$searchedValue` need write `function ($e) use ($searchedValue) { `

Answer (score 31):

Using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index will save time if you need to find multiple times:

```
$lookup = array_column($arr, NULL, 'id');   // re-index by 'id'
```

Then you can simply `$lookup[$id]` at will.

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
$entry = current(array_filter($array, function($e) use($v){ return $e->ID==$v; }));
```

working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/332fb6032d8ea6129fa0af12aab35ea6aa32695d)

Comment: it won't stop at the first found element, will it?

Comment: @yaugenka - correct, it first creates an array containing all the matches. Then `current` returns the first one, or `false` if there are no matches. [Recommend testing result using `=== false`, not `== false`.] IMHO, this use of `current` is a bit obscure. OTOH, it is well-defined and documented.

Answer (score 14):

```
class ArrayUtils
{
    public static function objArraySearch($array, $index, $value)
    {
        foreach($array as $arrayInf) {
            if($arrayInf->{$index} == $value) {
                return $arrayInf;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using it the way you wanted would be something like:

```
ArrayUtils::objArraySearch($array,'ID',$v);
```

Answer (score 7):

Fixing a small mistake of the [@YurkaTim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17694792/2153237), your solution work for me but adding `use`:

To use `$searchedValue`, inside of the function, one solution can be `use ($searchedValue)` after function parameters `function ($e) HERE`.

the `array_filter` function only return on `$neededObject` the if the condition on return is `true`

**If `$searchedValue` is a string or integer:**

```
$searchedValue = 123456; // Value to search.
$neededObject = array_filter(
    $arrayOfObjects,
    function ($e) use ($searchedValue) {
        return $e->id == $searchedValue;
    }
);
var_dump($neededObject); // To see the output
```

**If `$searchedValue` is array where we need check with a list:**

```
$searchedValue = array( 1, 5 ); // Value to search.
$neededObject  = array_filter(
    $arrayOfObjects,
    function ( $e ) use ( $searchedValue ) {
        return in_array( $e->term_id, $searchedValue );
    }
);
var_dump($neededObject); // To see the output
```

Comment: I think last line should be `var_dump($neededObject);` :)

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes like using the [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function to carry out the search. It's similar to array_filter() but does not affect the searched array, allowing you to carry out *multiple* searches on the same array of objects.

```
$haystack = array($obj1, $obj2, ...); //some array of objects
$needle = 'looking for me?'; //the value of the object's property we want to find

//carry out the search
$search_results_array = array_reduce(
  $haystack,

  function($result_array, $current_item) use ($needle){
      //Found the an object that meets criteria? Add it to the the result array 
      if ($current_item->someProperty == $needle){
          $result_array[] = $current_item;
      }
      return $result_array;
  },
  array() //initially the array is empty (i.e.: item not found)
);

//report whether objects found
if (count($search_results_array) > 0){
  echo "found object(s): ";
  print_r($search_results_array[0]); //sample object found
} else {
  echo "did not find object(s): ";
}
```

Comment: You have a typo inside your conditional where you're adding tot he results_array. It should be this: ```if ($current_item->someProperty == $needle){
          $result_array[] = $current_item;
      }```

Comment: Adjusted. Thanks @adrum !

Comment: Re *"It's similar to array_filter() but does not affect the searched array, allowing you to carry out multiple searches"*: You seem to be under the mistaken impression that `array_filter` modifies the original array. It does not. Your function to create a $result_array is exactly what array_filter already does! [AndreyP's later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55515785/199364) is the efficient way to use `array_reduce`; I see no circumstance in which this answer is useful - just use AndreyP's answer. If you want to stop at the first item, then write a function that stops at the first item!!

Answer (score 2):

Way to instantly get first value:

```
$neededObject = array_reduce(
    $arrayOfObjects,
    function ($result, $item) use ($searchedValue) {
        return $item->id == $searchedValue ? $item : $result;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with some sort of Java keymap.
If you do that, you do not need to loop over your objects array every time.

```
<?php

//This is your array with objects
$object1 = (object) array('id'=>123,'name'=>'Henk','age'=>65);
$object2 = (object) array('id'=>273,'name'=>'Koos','age'=>25);
$object3 = (object) array('id'=>685,'name'=>'Bram','age'=>75);
$firstArray = Array($object1,$object2);
var_dump($firstArray);

//create a new array
$secondArray = Array();
//loop over all objects
foreach($firstArray as $value){
    //fill second        key          value
    $secondArray[$value->id] = $value->name;
}

var_dump($secondArray);

echo $secondArray['123'];
```

output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'id' => int 123
      public 'name' => string 'Henk' (length=4)
      public 'age' => int 65
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => int 273
      public 'name' => string 'Koos' (length=4)
      public 'age' => int 25
array (size=2)
  123 => string 'Henk' (length=4)
  273 => string 'Koos' (length=4)
Henk
```

Comment: Ah, reindexing the array by id!  I do this commonly and it makes things nicer.

Comment: [Museful's later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167939/199364) accomplishes this in a single line of code, using `array_column` to re-index. Valid starting with PHP 5.5

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by keying the array with the ID. It's simpler and possibly faster for this scenario where the ID is what you're looking for.

```
[420] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Mary
         )

[10957] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Blah
         )
...
```

Now I can directly address the array:

```
$array[$v]->name = ...
```

Or, if I want to verify the existence of an ID:

```
if (array_key_exists($v, $array)) { ...
```

Comment: [Museful's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167939/199364) shows how to accomplish this, for an existing array, using `array_column`. Its generally preferable to do what he shows, as that also includes the `id` value as part of the object. For example, if the object is passed to another function, the `id` does not need to be separately passed.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I did see that Museful used array_column.  I offered this solution, because respectfully, I'll argue that array_column is generally not preferable in busy applications for a couple reasons.

First, re-indexing an array of objects rather than simply keying the data as it's loaded is CPU wasteful.

Second, storing ID twice is memory wasteful.  Why not just pass the ID, and let my external function reference the existing array?  Passing an object doesn't clone it, so if I truly need a clone, I could add the ID at that point.

Comment: I agree that if you have control over building the data in the first place, then `array_column` is not needed, so its cost is a moot point. I would key by id at that time, of course. Just be aware that if you ever find yourself needing to pass id *with* the other data, the optimal change is to accept the duplication of id, and add that id into the built data - rather than making some other change later in the data flow. The memory cost of duplicating id is negligible, and should not influence design decisions.

Answer (score -1):

```
      $keyToLookFor = $term->name;
      $foundField = array_filter($categories, function($field) use($keyToLookFor){
      return $field -> name === $keyToLookFor; });

      if(!empty($foundField)){
      $ke = array_keys($foundField);
      $ke = $ke[0];
      $v = $foundField[$ke]->id;}
```

**Am Working On Wordpress Theme Get Total Comment from Catagories And This help me out for Arrays**