# PHP How to get key name from value if array is multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following array and getting this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UnitIdx] => 10
            [Title] => 순차
            [Description] => 
            [NumSteps] => 9
            [ThumbnailPathName] => Level_1_Unit_thumbnail_Small.png
            [Step_1] => 4
            [Step_2] => 5
            [Step_3] => 6
            [Step_4] => 7
            [Step_5] => 8
            [Step_6] => 9
            [Step_7] => 10
            [Step_8] => 11
            [Step_9] => 12
            [Step_10] => 0
            [Step_11] => 0
            [Step_12] => 0
            [Step_13] => 0
            [Step_14] => 0
            [Step_15] => 0
            [Step_16] => 0
            [Step_17] => 0
            [Step_18] => 0
            [Step_19] => 0
            [Step_20] => 0
        )
)
```

Now I want to find key form value. For example value is `11` so key is `Step_8`.

Any idea how to return key name from value?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4742903/3933332

Comment: You do realise that a stdClass object isn't an array? And that those aren't keys, but properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search your key by value using [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and converting your Object into PHP array by [typecasting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), below is an example:

```
<?php

    $object = array();
    $object[0] = new StdClass;
    $object[0]->foo = 1;
    $object[0]->bar = 2;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($object);
    echo "</pre>";

    $key = array_search ('2', (array) $object[0]);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($key);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [foo] => 1
            [bar] => 2
        )

)

bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
<?php
//this part of code is for prepare sample data which is similar to your data
$class = new stdClass;

$class->prop1 = 'prop1';
$class->prop2 = 'prop2';

$array = array($class);

//THIS IS METHOD FOR SEARCH KEY BY VALUE
print_r(array_search('prop1',json_decode(json_encode($array[0]), true))); //you are looking for key for value 'prop1'
```

**Check working fiddle: [CLICK!](https://eval.in/552682)**

***Explanation:***

**1) `json_decode(json_encode($array[0]), true)`** - because you have in your array `stdClass` object, you can't use `array_search` function. So this line converts `$array[0]` element, which is `stdClass` object to an array. Now we can use `array_search` function to search key by specific value.

**2) `print_r(array_search('prop1',json_decode(json_encode($array[0]), true)));`** - we are using `array_search` function to get key of array element which value is equal to `prop1`. Documentation of this function says:

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the
>   corresponding key if successful

So we getting key corresponding to `prop1` value, which is `prop1`. `print_r` function shows us result. Instead of that you can assign result of operation to a variable and use it in other parts of code, for example:

```
$variable = array_search('prop1',json_decode(json_encode($array[0]), true));
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain me with my example as I am not getting clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Happy, I've added explanation.