# Why does json_decode not working?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get value of `c_user, xs, fr` and `date` value through JSON from below code and save it to database but it is not working here is my code which I used.

```php
$data = $_GET["user"];
$data = json_decode($data);
$datr = $data->datr;
$xs = $data->xs;
$fr = $data->fr;
$c_user = $data->c_user;
$token2 = $data->access_token;
$id = $data->uid;
```

*Here is the Json code*

```json
{
    "session_key" : "5.rWdMmED7nybZ1w.1513220229.45-100007001746590",
    "uid" : 100007001746590,
    "secret" : "b3f2dac4a948407864ff2e4e2d8feebf",
    "access_token" : "EAAAAAYsX7TsBAGSNv9YET43NxPk7PZBt1gTP0ipqQpb7ojzgn9pFf8hOLTg6V1R8IAv0y5TYgMhDlbCA0eHUN5aPOYw1DgA4c7vTgscbzY0tZALxpBk1tvIXPAisZBBZBzkyimkBurkU3iz0KmXoLQU1KY7tjxrgl7Wvxf5GwZBQbDFX4m5kMsYYDZB9UwIyl6YJA12Ac2ZBmcQBKAfOotc",
    "machine_id" : "hegxWhFD-5BKWnhTe3exWvAG",
    "session_cookies" : [
        {
            "name" : "c_user",
            "value" : "100007001746590",
            "expires" : "Fri,
             14 Dec 2018 02 : 57 : 09 GMT",
             "expires_timestamp" : 1544756229,
            "domain" : ".facebook.com",
            "path" : "\/",
            "secure" : true
        },
        {
            "name" : "xs",
            "value" : "45 : rWdMmED7nybZ1w : 2 : 1513220229 : 13473 : 4832",
            "expires" : "Fri,
             14 Dec 2018 02 : 57 : 09 GMT",
             "expires_timestamp" : 1544756229,
            "domain" : ".facebook.com",
            "path" : "\/",
            "secure" : true,
            "httponly" : true
        },
        {
            "name" : "fr",
            "value" : "0DfY4nJ3NUUeFKIUG.AWX4RKAQ0wBcl677F8jXJcCZ7Dc.BZj9JZ.fD.Fox.0.0.BaMeiF.AWXzlwrU",
            "expires" : "Fri,
             14 Dec 2018 02 : 57 : 09 GMT",
             "expires_timestamp" : 1544756229,
            "domain" : ".facebook.com",
            "path" : "\/",
            "secure" : true,
            "httponly" : true
        },
        {
            "name" : "datr",
            "value" : "hegxWhFD-5BKWnhTe3exWvAG",
            "expires" : "Sat,
             14 Dec 2019 02 : 57 : 09 GMT",
             "expires_timestamp" : 1576292229,
            "domain" : ".facebook.com",
            "path" : "\/",
            "secure" : true,
            "httponly" : true
        }
    ],
    "confirmed" : true,
    "identifier" : "7250492401"
}
```

NOTE: I have success in getting `$token2` and `$id`. How to get the values of `xs, fr, date, c_user`?

Comment: Those values don't appear in the JSON data you posted...

Comment: there is no such key as `c_user` in your json data

Comment: Than what I have to do to get that data

Comment: I want value of c_user name

Comment: I can't see any of these keys in your JSON string. And as I can see these are values of the 'name' property.

Comment: Yes I need values of name property

Comment: @NalinNishant checkout the answer i posted.

Comment: @Cœur Sorry, missed that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see. The values you're asking about are elements of a JSON *array*, with "name" values like "xs" and "fr". You will need to iterate through the array in order to unpack it.

```
$cookies = [];
foreach ($data->session_cookies as $cookie) {
    $cookies[$cookie->name] = $cookie->value;
}
$xs = $cookies['xs'];
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be consistent for all of your missing keys.  Take `xs` for example.  The code you wrote looks for a child element labeled `xs`:

```
$xs = $data->xs;
```

But this doesn't exist in your JSON document.  Instead, you need to parse through the `session_cookies` array to find an element where the `name` key is set to `xs`.  This method is described in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-a-array-of-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Approximately this is what you are looking for. I guess.

```
$data = $_GET["user"];
$data = json_decode($data);
$c_user = [];
foreach($data->session_cookies as $key => $val)
{
    $c_user[] = $val['name']; 
}
```

now in the `c_user` array you have the value you require.