# PHP database looping through array to find id, then using id to display values from that column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

Currently I have been able to find the correct table and `print_r` the content of the array. Now I'm trying to loop through that array and display usernames and points from that array based on the id. This is what the array looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 5a61d2f40394d
[first] => Test
[last] => Guy3
[company] => 123 Company
[points] => 50
[url] => https://example.com/points/?user=5a61d2f40394d
[created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[updated] => 2018-01-19 06:22:42
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 5a61cdddc359d
[first] => Test
[last] => Guy1
[company] => 123 Company
[points] => 0
[url] => https://example.com/points/?user=5a61cdddc359d
[created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[updated] => 2018-01-19 05:52:13
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 5a61d054a0915
[first] => Test
[last] => Guy2
[company] => 123 Company
[points] => 0
[url] => https://example.com/points/?user=5a61d054a0915
[created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[updated] => 2018-01-19 06:02:44
)

)
```

This is what I've written so far and I've been able to find the id but now I want to access the points and update them after..

```
global $wpdb; //this is wordpress so I'm accessing the database
//here I'm reading the variable ?user= in the url
$queryURL = parse_url( html_entity_decode( esc_url( add_query_arg( $arr_params ) ) ) );
parse_str( $queryURL['query'], $getVar );
$user = $getVar['user'];

$customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wpjw_skmember`;");
//I've found the users id but now I need to update their points but I don't know how.
$first = array_column($customers, 'id');

foreach($first as $value) {
   if  ($value == $user) {
       echo 'user found'
   }    
}
```

Comment: Why not just write an UPDATE query using the user id?  No SELECT.  No looping search.  If you need to search a multidimensional array, StackOverflow has pre-existing solutions for this.

Comment: I'm still learning so how would this look?

Comment: You have not explained how you are updating the data and what output you want to display.  Your question is Too Broad / Unclear to answer properly.  Is your posted object array `$customers` or something else?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [PHP - find entry by object property from a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-a-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $customers array is of the format posted above, then accessing values within it would work like this:

```
echo $customers[0]->last; // returns "Guy3"
```

So, you could loop over $customers and test each customer within that array to see if the ID value matches, then access the other values when it does:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer){
    if ($customer->id == $user){
        echo $customer->last . " has " . $customer->points . " points!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Using break after identifying the matching user will exit from the foreach loop, preventing additional needless iterations.

Comment: This is an unrefined and partial solution to the question.  This method will perform needless iterations after finding the user.  Additionally, the OP's array is an array of objects, so your solution simply won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work I'm unable to access $customers['id'] I've tried to just print_r($customers['id']); and nothing shows

Comment: mickmack was initially correct, but I believe I have now updated the answer to correctly access object properties as well as prevent additional needless iterations.