# How do you search for an instance of a class in php

Tags: php, arrays, class, search

I am trying to search for an instance of a class in PHP but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do this, other than the obvious of recursing through each item in an array and checking the values.
I was hoping someone can help if there is a way to do this.
Here is an example

```
class Item {
    public $item;
    public $test;
    public function __construct($item) {
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->test = sprintf("%d - Hello", $item);
    }
}

$array = [];
for($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $array[] = new Item($i);
}

$foundItem = array_search(75, array_column($array, "item"));
echo print_r($foundItem, true);
```

I want `$foundItem` to be the entire object returned.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-a-array-of-objects

Comment: I needed to avoid looping through the whole array

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` returns the key of the item in the array. Since you've still got your full array in scope, you can use this to access the entire object with a simple change:

```
$foundItem = $array[array_search(75, array_column($array, "item"))];
```

See https://3v4l.org/6k6nE (note that this needs PHP 7+, since `array_column` didn't work on an array of objects until then)

There are also a few other approaches you could use for this (although you said you wanted to avoid looping over the objects manually). `array_column` supports re-indexing an array by a given column using the third argument, so this would remove the need to use `array_search`:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'item');
$foundItem = $array[75];
```

Comment: Just tested this on php fiddle and it works fine. However, just tested on server and doesn't work as only has 5.3.  DO you have any other ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Well my first thought would be to try and upgrade the server, but if that's not an option then there are ways of adding `array_column` support to earlier versions, [like this polyfill](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column)