# how to grab json id by searching name value using php

Tags: javascript, php, json, select, weather

```
 {
    "id": 833,
    "name": "mumbai",
    "state": "",
    "country": "IN",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 47.159401,
      "lat": 34.330502
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2960,
    "name": "‘kolkata",
    "state": "",
    "country": "IN",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 36.321911,
      "lat": 34.940079
    }
  },
```

I want if i define $name = kolkata ; then it should show its id as 2960

using php guys please help

```
$name = kolkata;
$data = file_get_contents('city.json'); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$citys = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-an-array-of-objects might help you. (P.S. the fact that the data used to be JSON is irrelevant. Once you've decoded it, it's just a list of objects. If you've been searching for solutions in relation to JSON, stop doing that and start searching for solutions relating to arrays and objects in PHP)

Comment: @ADyson its not helping

Comment: Show what you tried from that, please, and what went wrong. I can't guess what specific problem you might have had.

Comment: i want to get the id from the above json when i search the name

Comment: @ADyson let me explain you as sql databse

Comment: @ADyson  $sql = "SELECT id FROM table_name where name = 'kolkata' "; just like this i want in json

Comment: Read my first comment again. After you write `json_decode()` then your `$citys` data is **NOT** JSON anymore. Stop thinking about JSON. It's now a PHP array. The link I gave you shows how to search through an array of PHP objects and find an item based on one of the properties of the objects, which is exactly what you're asking for. Try it. If you fail somehow, please add the code you tried. was there something there which you still don't understand?

Comment: @ADyson got it bro thanks

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc91d57ac0b9c40ac391afc7aa0a878e174a8aac

Comment: @ADyson you are awesome pal thank you sooooo much for your help :D