# Read array and find value

Tags: php, arrays, json

From an API request I receive JSON data. This is a dump of the array

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 28257
        [price] => 18.50
        [meta_data] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [id] => 522793
                [key] => meta_image_out
                [value] => motor-watermerk.png
            )
            [1] => Array(
                [id] => 522794
                [key] => saveLoc
                [value] => Balie
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The data what I want is the value from

```
[1] => Array(
    [id] => 522794
    [key] => saveLoc
    [value] => Balie
)
```

for this I can use

```
echo $array[0]['meta_data'][1]['value'];
```

But the sequence from the array can be different and this code works not anymore.

```
$array[0]['meta_data'][**1**]['value'];
```

Number **1** can also `2, 3, 4...`

How can I get always this value from the array?

The key is always **saveLoc**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - find entry by object property from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-an-array-of-objects). It's for arrays of objects, but the same principle can be applied to arrays of (associative) arrays, just by tweaking the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. No need to worry about array index

```
    $data = [];
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        $metaData = $arr['meta_data'];
        foreach ($metaData as $metaD) {
            if ($metaD['key'] == 'saveLoc') {
                $data = $metaD;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```