# PHP Manipulate $_Session array shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i'm struggling with some shopping cart exercise...
I would like to have one function which takes care of all my adding items logic.

When selecting an item, it should add it to my cart. If there is no item yet in the cart, it should be added with amount 1. After adding the same item again, it should increase the amount.

What i have up to now looks like this:

```
public function addToCart($id){

        $this->articleName = ($this->getArticleNamefromID($id)[0]["name"]);

        if ($_SESSION['cart'] == null){

            $array = ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1];
            array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $array);

        }else{

            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

                if($value["articleName"] != $this->articleName){

                    $array = ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1];
                    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $array);

                }else {

                    $amountInc = $value["amount"] + 1;
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]["amount"] = $amountInc;

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

The first item will be add up as expected (in this case daycream), when i try to insert a new item (nightcream), it will stack up like this instead of counting up the amount:

```
Cart:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Daycream
            [amount] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [articleName] => Nightcream
            [amount] => 1
        )

)
```

$this->articleName is a sql call to the db and gives me always the selected item, this should be ok. I guess I have some issues with `foreach($value["articleName"] != $this->articleName)`
My intend was to check if the current value from cart matches the given articleName, if so count amount + 1 or add a new item into the cart.

Can you maybe help me?

Thx in advance!

**EDIT1**
added array_filter for getting current articleName

```
public function addToCart($id){

        $this->articleName = ($this->getArticleNamefromID($id)[0]["name"]);

        if ($_SESSION['cart'] == null){

            $array = ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1];
            array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $array);

        }else{

            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {

                $currentItem = array_filter(
                    $_SESSION['cart'], function ($e) use (&$searchedValue) {
                        return $e->articleName == $searchedValue;
                    }
                );

                //Check values
                echo $this->articleName. " vs. " . $currentItem;

                if($currentItem == $this->articleName){

                    $amountInc = $value["amount"] + 1;
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]["amount"] = $amountInc;

                }else {

                    $array = ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1];
                    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $array);

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)` iterates over your entire cart. Each time it find an item that doesn't match (for example, looking for "Nightcream" but finding the first item which is "Daycream"), it adds a new record to the end. You want to check the entire array for any matching records. Try [PHP - find entry by object property from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4742903/283366)

Comment: Yeah that seems legit. How can i iterate through the current item?

I'm trying to get the current articleName with this:
`
$neededObject = array_filter(
                    $item,
                    function ($e) use (&$searchedValue) {
                        return $e->articleName == $searchedValue;
                    }
                );
`
--> Trying to get property 'articleName' of non-object in ...

Comment: you're right...updated

Answer (score 0):

OK...i solved it like this:

```
public function addToCart($id)
    {

        $this->articleName = ($this->getArticleNamefromID($id)[0]["name"]);

        if ($_SESSION['cart'] == null) {

            array_push($_SESSION['cart'], ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1]);

        } else {

            if (!$this->articleInCart()){
                $array = ["articleName" => $this->articleName, "amount" => 1];
                array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $array);
            }

        }

    }

 private function articleInCart()
    {

        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value["articleName"] == $this->articleName) {
                $amountInc = $value["amount"] + 1;
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]["amount"] = $amountInc;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```