# how to check if particular item exists in associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

```
[
 {
 "pid": "1",
 "pname": "Burger",
 "price": "20",
 "qnty": "1",
 "pimg": "1.jpg"
 },
 {
 "pid": "2",
 "pname": "Cheese burger",
 "price": "30",
 "qnty": "1",
 "pimg": "2.jpg"
 }
]
```

I have an array like above. how to check if array has particular **"pid"**.

for an example if array has **"pid" 1** then display `view button` otherwise display `add to cart button`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - find entry by object property from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = [
 {
 "pid": "1",
 "pname": "Burger",
 "price": "20",
 "qnty": "1",
 "pimg": "1.jpg"
 },
 {
 "pid": "2",
 "pname": "Cheese burger",
 "price": "30",
 "qnty": "1",
 "pimg": "2.jpg"
 }
]
```

You can use `isset` fucntion.

```
$key = 1;
$count =0 ;

foreach($array as $a) {
    if(isset(array_search($key,$a))){
       //your logic to execute if the $key is there in the array
       $count ++;
   }
 }
  if($count==0){
      //add to cart logic
  }
```

Comment: Your second part of code is not a valid one its totally wrong.

Comment: You cannot validate the key by `empty()` .See the https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Because we do not have assignment operator in the array.

Comment: i want to check if array has particular "pid" and if yes then display "view button" because pid is already in array and if not exists in array then display " add to cart button"  but here if pid is not exists then "add to cart button" displays as much as keys available in array. if pid is exists then it display view button which is ok

Comment: @Maulik what i have done here is assigning the value that you want to find in the array which is assigned to `pid` and loop through the array to find if the value is assigned to pid in the loop using `array_search`.

Comment: @Maulik do you want to add those buttons according to the data that you have in each sub array or just one buton using the main array

Comment: suppose i have 3 product with 3 individual  page. if i go to page no.1 then there should be add to cart button if that product is not in array. if that product is already in array then hide add to cart and show view cart button. as per your code if product is not in cart then i am seeing more than 1  buttons( total buttons is equal to products in array ) of add to cart because of foreach loop. i just want vice versa of add to cart and view cart

Comment: can you add your code to the question ( button handling part)

Comment: @Maulik i think i just realized what you really want.And i have updated the answer. Check if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $item){
   if($item->pid == 1) {
       //do some work...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of **isset()** & **!empty()**

```
foreach($lists as $list) {
    if(isset($list['pid']) && (!empty($list['pid']))) { // this will check if a key exists. If yes, then check for it's value. If value is there, then true
        // pid exists and has a value
    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate array using loop and then check the value against any index of array

```
foreach ($items as $item){
   if($item->pid == 1) {
       // do whatever you want to do
   }
}
```