# Access JSON objects value in PHP without a loop

Tags: php, json

I wonder how to access objects' values without a loop in a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "adresse": "",
  "longitude": "12.352",
  "latitude": "61.2191",
  "precision": "",
  "Stats": [
    {
      "id": "300",
      "carte_stat": "1154€",
    },
    {
      "id": "301",
      "carte_stat": "1172€",
    },
    {
      "id": "302",
      "carte_stat": "2293€",
    },
  ],
}
```

I'd like to target for example the object with id '301'.
Using a loop I do like this:

```
foreach($result_json['Stats'] as $v) {

    if ($v['id'] == "301") {
        ...
    }

};
```

But How can I do without loop?

I tried things like this but in vain:

```
$result_json['Stats'][id='301']['carte_stat'];
$result_json['Stats']['id']->{'301'};
```

Comment: I don't think you can with plain PHP.

Comment: You can't. You would need to know the exact numeric index at which that element is stored, e.g. `$result_json['Stats'][1]`.

Comment: since $result_json['Stats'] is an array and "id" is not a index, you must loop through it to "see" the values inside it. But why do you don't want loop?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers.
Not using loops would have allowed me to have a lighter code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - find entry by object property from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Not exactly but thank you

Comment: Not using a classic loop will prevent you from using a `break` for improved efficiency.  Follow ADyson's advice and add a `break` to your coding attempt.  See the duplicate for all of the different ways to do this task.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with array_filter.
Get the first occurence of id 301:

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);

$result = current(array_filter($json['Stats'], function($e) {
    return $e['id'] == 301;
}));

print_r($result);
```

For/foreach will probably be faster. You shouldn't aim for "ligther code" when it will be a problem for readability or performance. Sometimes, more is less (problems).

Comment: Already demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151946/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You could index the `Stats` using `array_column()` to convert it.  It's less efficient than a loop as it will first convert the entire array before you can access it by the id...

```
$stats = array_column($result_json['Stats'], "carte_stat", "id");

echo $stats['301'];
```

Note that I have to fix your JSON, but I assume this was due to chopping out data not needed for the question.

Comment: Same basic effect as https://stackoverflow.com/a/44167939/2943403